# On decomposition of Conformal transformation: Liouville Theorem's

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analysis, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, a mapping $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is called conformal transform if it preserves the angle between curves. Namely, if $u,v :I\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $u(0)= v(0)$. Where $I\subset \mathbb{R}$  is an open interval containing $0$.
then 
\begin{equation}
\cos^{-1} \left(\frac{\overset{.}{u}(0)}{\|\overset{.}{u}(0)\|}\cdot \frac{\overset{.}{v}(0)}{\|\overset{.}{v}(0)\|}\right) 
=\cos^{-1} \left(\frac{\overset{.}{Tu}(0)}{\|\overset{.}{Tu}(0)\|}\cdot \frac{\overset{.}{Tv}(0)}{\|\overset{.}{Tv}(0)\|}\right)
\end{equation}
where $x\cdot y $ is the usual scalar product of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\|.\|$ is the corresponding Euclidean norm.

> **Question**
>   It is stated as obvious result in the book of Lieb Loss and Eliot (Analysis second edition) page 120 Lemma 4.8 that any such Conformal Transformation is product of Euclidean group **(Please what is the Euclidean group?),** scaling map, translation. **In short it can be written as product of similitudes.**

As well the result is well known in the complex plane thank to the Mobius maps.

**I would like to know where or how  can one  find or prove of the above statement in higher dimension $n\ge3$?**

Any prove or help is welcome.

Comment: I think you meant $\cos^{-1}$ to turn scalar products of normalized vectors into angles. But that part is actually irrelevant; you might as well require the dot products themselves to be equal. The Euclidean group would be the group of all isometric (i.e. length-preserving) transformations. I'm surprised they list translations separately, as I'd include them.

Comment: You are right I just fixed it . thanks

Comment: You are right I just fixed it . As well we can get rid of $\cos^{-1}$.  I think also one can include translation as well in the Euclidean group. but they stated it that way

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to prove directly, but is an easy corollary of [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(conformal_mappings)). Once you have this theorem, use the general formula for the Moebius transformation given in the link:
$$
f(x)= b + \frac{\alpha A(x-a)}{|x-a|^{\epsilon}}, \epsilon\in \{0, 2\},
$$
where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, $\alpha$ is a scalar and $a, b$ are vectors in $R^n$. Since in your case $f$ sends $R^n$ to itself, $\epsilon=0$ and you are done.