# Differential of the inversion

Tags: calculus, geometry, jacobian

Let us consider the inversion in $\mathbb R^2$ with respect to the unit circle : $$ f(x,y) = \left(\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}, \frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}\right)$$

I found the Jacobian matrix (and wolfram agree with me) given by $$ \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \begin{pmatrix} y^2 & -xy \\ -xy & x^2 \end{pmatrix}$$

However this has determinant zero which is absurd ... Where is the mistake ? Thanks !

Comment: Be a sane person and work in polar coordinates

Comment: THe correct inversion is $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(x,y)$. Your map is not at all an inversion (as the answer below mentions it sends everything to the unit circle).

Comment: @peek-a-boo : great, thanks a lot !

Comment: In the spirit of @LegNaiB 's answer, your map isn't invertible. I.e, the vectors $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ get mapped to the same point under $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the case because your map has not inversion. You're taking all elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the unit circle. Thus you can regain the direction of your point, but you cannot regain the distance from $(0,0)$:

We have $f((1,0)) = (1,0)$ and $f((2,0)) = (1,0)$. Thus you have no isomorphism and no invertible map and that means that the Jacobian has a determinant of $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time believing your map is the inversion. In polar, inversion through the unit circle is represent as follows:

$$ (r ,\theta) \to ( \frac{1}{r}, \theta)$$

Now, let's compute the jacobian:

$$ \frac{ \partial( \frac{1}{r}, \theta)}{\partial(r ,\theta)} = \begin{vmatrix} -\frac{1}{r^2} & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{vmatrix}= - \frac{1}{r^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let me consider inversion suggested in @peek-a-boo comment and write $\xi = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $\eta=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$. Then $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \xi} = - \frac{\partial y}{\partial \eta} = \frac{\eta^2-\xi^2}{(\eta^2+\xi^2)^2}$ and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \eta} = - \frac{\partial y}{\partial \xi} = -\frac{2\eta\xi}{(\eta^2+\xi^2)^2}$. Then Jakobian
$$\frac{D(x,y)}{D(\xi,\eta)}=-\frac{1}{(\eta^2+\xi^2)^2}\lt 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Your transformation is normalization (transforming a vector into its normalized version). It's not inversion with respect to unit circle which is:

$$(x,y) \ \mapsto \ \left(\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2},\dfrac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

See this answer for a detailed computation and geometrical interpretation: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2621344